# How can I get the rank of rows relative to total number of rows based on a field?

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a `scores` table that has two fields:

- user_id
- score

I'm fetching specific rows that match a list of user_id's. How can I determine a rank for each row relative to the total number of rows, based on `score`? The rows in the result set are not necessarily sequential (the scores will vary widely from one row to the next). I'm not sure if this matters, but `user_id` is a unique field.

**Edit**

@Greelmo

I'm already ordering the rows. If I fetch 15 rows, I don't want the rank to be 1-15. I need it to be the position of that row compared against the entire table by the `score` property. So if I have 200 rows, one row's rank may be 3 and another may be 179 (these are arbitrary #'s for example only).

**Edit 2**

I'm having some luck with this query, but I actually want to avoid ties

```
    SELECT
       s.score
       , s.created_at
       , u.name
       , u.location
       , u.icon_id
       , u.photo
       , (SELECT COUNT(*) + 1 FROM scores WHERE score > s.score) AS rank
    FROM
        scores s
    LEFT JOIN
        users u ON u.uID = s.user_id
    ORDER BY
        s.score DESC
        , s.created_at DESC
    LIMIT 15
```

If two or more rows have the same score, I want the latest one (or earliest - I don't care) to be ranked higher. I tried modifying the subquery with `AND id > s.id` but that ended up giving me an unexpected result set and different ties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select S.score, S.created_at, U.name
   , U.location, U.icon_id, U.photo
   , (Select Count(*) + 1
        From scores S2
        Where S2.score > S.score
            Or (S2.score = S.Score And S2.created_at > S.created_at)
        ) AS rank
From scores S
    Left Join users U 
        On U.uID = S.user_id
Order By S.score DESC, S.created_at DESC
LIMIT 15
```

Of course, if it is possible for two scores to have the same created_at date, then you will still get ties and need to determine a third tie-breaker.

Answer (score 0):

You could order the data in your query.

```
SELECT user_id, score FROM table ORDER BY score ASC;
```

This will give you your data from lowest score to highest.

If this doesn't answer your question, then I don't understand what you're asking.

**EDIT**

To get the position, while iterating through the database results, just keep a counter.